# Best practices when making a Yii2 Extension

Tags: yii2

What are the best way to create a extension for Yii?

Here is what i have done so far

1. I want it to be installable via composer, so i created a github repo for it.
2. I have the files locally in the folder `vendor/githubname/projectname/` in my Yii2 project

Now my questions are: How do i register the extension with the application - ex. get to to work on myproject.com/myextension and how do i organize views, controllers and models within the extension?

I've googled around for a good tutorial, but i have not found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been at the same point and had to find all the information myself. As this might help others as well, I will document each step in detail.

## 1. Github setup

Create a new github repo and make sure you follow the naming conventions for yii2-extensions. Ideally they are like this:

```
yourcompany/yii2-yourextension
```

`yourcompany` being your github-scope and `yourextension` the name of your extension.

## 2. Local project setup

Create a local folder where you will be developing your extension. The one file you create in there first is `composer.json`. This folder should not be in the vendor-folder of an existing project! It won't work anyway, except you declared your namespaces within `autoload.php` of your surrounding project manually.

#### composer.json

The most important parts in there are:

- the dependencies (usually the Yii2-framework)
- the autoload-property which declares the namespace for your package. This will later be used by yiis-autoloader to find your classes.

When you finished this, you can run `composer update` This will create the vendor folder containing all your referenced libraries.

Here is an Example of one of our extensions:
https://github.com/asinfotrack/yii2-toolbox/blob/master/composer.json

Pay special attention to the autoload block at the end of the file! In this case this tells the autoloader that `asinfotrack/yii2/toolbox` will be mapped to the root-folder of the project. If you have a folder `models` with the class `MyModel.php` in your project root, it should have the namespace `asinfotrack/yii2/toolbox/models`. Got it? This is crucial for your extension to work!

#### .gitignore

The next file you will be creating is the `.gitignore`-file. In there you exlude the vendor-folder and all your IDE-specific files.

Also an example of the same extension mentioned above. You can simply copy/paste it:
https://github.com/asinfotrack/yii2-toolbox/blob/master/.gitignore

#### Git-repo-setup

Now its time to initialize the git-repo. Simply navigate into the directory and execute the command `git init`. To add all files and commit for the first time you execute `git add -A` and the `git commit -m "your message here"`. You are now ready to push your repo to github.

Your need to set the remote of your repo to github. This is done with the following command:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/youraccount/yourrepo.git
```

Also make sure that the following config vars are set correctly:

```
git config user.email
git config user.name
```

At least the email should match your github-account. If you want to change the values, simply append them to the commands above. Like so:

```
git config user.email "my-mail@my-domain.com"
```

You are now ready to push your extension to github:

```
git push origin master
```

## 3. Packagist-setup

For other users to be able to reference your extension from within their projects, you need to register it with [packagist.org](http://packagist.org).

Create an account and submit your extension as explained here:
https://packagist.org/packages/submit

You simply need to provide your repos github-url. Make sure you follow the naming conventions for yii2.

## 4. Connecting packagist and github

Packagist mirrors your repo for further distribution. If you skip this step, you have to tell packagist each time you updated your github-repo. This can be automated!

Go to the settings of your github-repo and navigate to `Webhooks & Services`. There you add a new hook for packagist. This is supported natively by github...you find the packagist-hook in the dropdown.

You will need to provide your packagist-API-Token which you can find on the top of your account-page when logged into packagist.org. Everything is documented very well here:

https://packagist.org/about

## 5. Conclusion

That's it already! When you perform a new commit to github, it will be mirrored automatically to packagist. With a few minutes delay you will receive the updated version of your extension when you execute `composer update`.

At first all of this might look intimidating and complicated, but actually its pretty straight forward. If you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask. I will then extend this answer.

If something is not clear, simply look at the files of one of our [extensions](https://github.com/asinfotrack).

Comment: Thank you for a thurough explanation! I'll give it a shot. +1

Comment: You're welcome! If you have problems somewhere, I might have missed something...just write I comment to this answer if so...I'll extend it immediately!

Comment: Do you have any experience with using repositories outside of github? Required in `"repositories"`instead of `"require"`? You see I have a repo that is private (and has to stay private) and i've set up SSH and the composer.json is valid (I know, cus i got an error at first - now i dont) but the composer just sais "nothing to install or upgrade" and my folder does not appear in vendor. Does a repo thats not loaded trough packagist require another file to work?

Comment: Hey @Jørgen! Not really...we tried it at our company but at that point it wasn't really working with composer. Since then we didn't try again. I just found [this guide](http://marekkalnik.tumblr.com/post/22929686367/composer-installing-package-from-local-git) which seems to be pretty straight forward. Did you try it like this?